# What is a Hadith?

Tags: hadith

I would like to know, what is a `Hadith` ?

What all books are considered to be taken into account as `Hadith` and what is there count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Hadith relative to Sunna is what is said by the Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) whether it said or done, a report, or a habit.

The Hadith is considered the second main source to Islamic laws after Qur'an according to most schools of *fiqh* as they represent the details of what Qur'an didn't mention, and a completion for what the Qur'an didn't talk about.

But we must pay attention while reading any Hadith since there are fake ones, and there are some writers who said Ahadith, but they are not 100% correct. This [link](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB_%D9%86%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%8A#.D9.83.D8.AA.D8.A8_.D8.A7.D9.84.D8.AD.D8.AF.D9.8A.D8.AB) discusses many of the books you asked for.

Comment: Do u have the English version for that link?

Comment: [This](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith) is an english version from wikipedia  hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hadith literally means saying. And refers to sayings of Prophet narrated by people. After Prophet SAWW there was bans on narration and writings of hadith and first hadith collections were by Bukhari and Kulayni when this ban was removed.

Most of hadith have usually 4-6 persons in their chain of narrators to reach prophet SAWW.

According to Shia Islam sayings of any of the fourteen infallibles are considered same as sayings of prophet SAWW because Shia believe prophet SAWW left his divine knowledge for Imam Ali a.s. and he left for second Imam (Imam Hasan a.s) and then left for Imam Hussain a.s. and so on and currently this knowledge is with [Imam Mahdi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_al-Mahdi) a.s. who is in Occultation.